# How to move/upload content documents in a specific folder with Salesforce REST API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, files, upload

I am working with Salesforce REST API to upload some files in the files tab.

I create a request with this data example,

```
content_obj = {
'attributes' : {'type' : 'ContentVersion', 'referenceId' : number_assign + '-' + get_entity},
'Title': data.get('attachmentName'),
'PathOnClient': data.get('path'),
'VersionData': data.get('encodedPath'),
 }

data_content = {'records' : datalst}

content_version = sf_api_call('/services/data/v53.0/composite/tree/ContentVersion', method="post", data=data_content, keys=keys)
```

Those files are store in files tab, not in a library/folder.

[image]

I would like to move/upload those files in a specific folder/library in files tab and not in the general files tab.

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried and exactly how (e.g. error text, unexpected behavior) it is not working.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237844/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-library-folder-using-apex

Comment: It is something similar, I will try to do with the API. Thanks guys